# Copy file skipping first n lines and last m lines

Tags: c, file-io, posix

I want to copy a file with skipping first n of its lines and last m lines using open, read, write and lseek
(eg. n = 1, m = 2, source file:

AAAAAAA

BBBBBBB

CCCCCCC

DDDDDDD

dest file:

BBBBBBB )

I know how to copy a file but don't know how to skip the lines. Here is my code for copy:

```
    char buf[128];
    size_t size;

    int source = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    int dest = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY);

    if(source == -1) {
            printf("error");
            return;
    }
    if(dest == -1) {
            printf("error");
            return;
    }

    while((size = read(source, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
            write(dest, buf, size);
    }

    close(source);
    close(dest);
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: How to skip the first N lines is obvious, isn't it? Just keep reading until you get past N newlines.

Comment: Why are you using `O_APPEND` on the output file? Do you really want to append to the end of the destination file, instead of overwriting it?

Comment: yea i shouldnt use O_APPEND my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `fgets` to read your file since that will read it line by line.

Because it is not trivial to say how many lines you have in total I would suggest you

- use `fgets` to read the file line by line
- skip outputting the first `n` lines
- write the rest to your output files and count the number of lines and remember the length of each.
- use `ftruncate` to truncate off the last `m` lines.

This should do the trick:

```
void copy_nm(char * source, char * dest, int n, int m) {
    FILE * in = fopen(source, "r");
    FILE * out = fopen(dest, "w");

    size_t file_length = 0;
    size_t line_lengths[m + 1];
    memset(line_lengths, 0 , sizeof(line_lengths));

    int lengths_iterator = 0;


    char buffer[0x400];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in)) {
        size_t length = strlen(buffer);

        if (n) { // skip this line
            if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n') // only if it is a real line
                n--;
            continue;
        }

        fwrite(buffer, length, 1, out);
        line_lengths[lengths_iterator] += length;
        file_length += length;

        if (buffer[length - 1] != '\n') { // line was longer then the buffer
            continue;
        }

        lengths_iterator++;
        lengths_iterator %= m+1;

        line_lengths[lengths_iterator] = 0;
    }

    for (lengths_iterator = 0; lengths_iterator < m+1; lengths_iterator++) {
        file_length -= line_lengths[lengths_iterator];
    }

    fseek(out, 0, SEEK_SET); // rewind before truncating
    ftruncate(fileno(out), file_length);

}
```

Comment: The only tricky thing is dealing with lines longer than your `fgets` buffer.

Comment: You don't need to remember the length of all the lines, just the last M lines. When you're done, subtract the total of these from the size of the file, and truncate to that length.

Comment: @Barmar lines longer then your buffer won't have a '\n' at the end, just check for that and you are good.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible, just that it's a little tricky. You have to check for that case and not increment the line counter.