# What is the most efficient way to remove first N bytes from a file on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi

Say, I have a file of an arbitrary length `S` and I need to remove first of its `N` bytes (where `N` is much less than `S`.) What is the most efficient way to do it on Windows?

I'm looking for a WinAPI to do this, if one is available.

Otherwise, what are my options -- to load it into RAM and then re-write the existing file with the remainder of data? (In this case I cannot be sure that the PC has enough RAM?) Or write the remainder of file data into a new file, erase the old one, and rename the new file into the old one. (In this case what to do if any of these steps fail? Plus how about defragmentation that this method causes on disk?)

Comment: This is an interesting question. I'm pretty sure there's not an optimal way to do this (i.e. a simple filesystem adjustment), but I hope I'm wrong!

Comment: @Antonio: I tried my first approach with loading it into RAM, but now I see that this may run into an issue if I cannot reserve enough RAM for a large file. Thus I thought to find an API to do this on the file-system level.

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19447627/335858)

Comment: Depending on the location of your file, you could use TxF to atomically replace the old file with the new file. This would likely be the fastest, though of course your drive needs enough space to hold the copy of the file.

Comment: The Old New Thing: [How do I delete bytes from the beginning of a file?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/01/10097859.aspx)

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks for finding the "Good old thing" article. Although, his idea of using sparse files requires NTFS file system, right? I can't rely on it. A user may still use FAT or FAT32 or some other file system. But still a good find! I didn't know that.

Comment: @c00: Sparse files only help, if the files never leave your application. As outlined in the blog entry, decommitted *space* still contributes to a file's *contents*. 'Removal' is simulated through offset adjustments inside your application. Since you are all focused on reading data into **RAM**, you may wish to study [Managing Virtual Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810627.aspx).

Comment: @ErykSun The Old New Thing is a 404.

Comment: @Teepeemm, Microsoft apparently moved developer blogs from blogs.msdn.com to devblogs.microsoft.com. Here's the current link: [How do I delete bytes from the beginning of a file?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101201-00/?p=12153). You can also paste the old link into the Wayback Machine. Here's a capture from [2015-07-11](https://web.archive.org/web/20150711031116/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/01/10097859.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way to do this built into the OS.  There are theoretical ways to edit the file system's data structures underneath the operating system on sector or cluster boundaries, but this is different for each file system, and would need to violate any security model.

To accomplish this you can read in the data starting at byte N in chunks of say 4k, and then write them back out starting at byte zero, and then use the file truncate command (setendoffile) to set the new smaller end of file when you are finished copying the data.

Comment: Can I do this by reading and also writing from the same file?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The most *efficient* method to delete data at the beginning of the file is to modify the directory entry, on the hard drive, that tells where the data starts.  Again, this is the most *efficient* method.

*Note:  This may not be possible, if the data must start on a new boundary.  If this is the case, you may have to write the remainder data on the sector(s) to new sector(s), essentially moving the data.*

The preferred method is to write a new file that starts with data copied after the deleted area.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do this from a user-mode code (not the kernel mode)? If so, then how?

Comment: It all depends on the OS you are using and the driver to the hard drive.  You may have to write your own driver in order to provide this functionality.  You will have to send commands directly to the hard drive, which is OS dependent.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. That's what I thought. I need it to be accessible from a WinAPI level (for Windows XP and up.)

Answer (score 0):

[Moving files on same drive is faster](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-faster-Copying-or-Moving-files-in-a-PC-Why) than copying files since data isn't duplicated; only the file pointer, (symbolic)links & file allocation/index table is updated.

The `move` command in CMD could be modified to allow user to set file start & end markers, effecting file truncation without copying file data, saving valuable time & RAM/Disk overheads.

Alternative would be to send the commands direct to the device/disk driver bypassing the Operating System as long as OS knows where to find the file & file properties eg. file size, name & sectors occupied on disk.

Comment: Current solutions being `dd` & `powershell` both copy file data (replicate) to enable truncation.

Comment: Of course with a hex editor one would just remove the redundant bytes ;)