# How to delete first block of bytes of a file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file, io

I want to delete first block of bytes in a file in matlab (ex: delete first 50 Byte of a text file)
is that possible in matlab?? if so, how to achieve that??

Comment: Do you want to do this **with** or **without** loading the file into memory?  One possible way is to read in the file with `fread` skip the first 50 bytes, read the rest of the data into memory and save that back into a new text file... but I can't really say for sure because you have given very little information.  What is it you're trying to do?  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: sorry but I don't want to load it into the memory.. nice idea though!

Comment: I'm trying to simulate nodes in a collection of P2P protocols, so the file represents cache and it can't be more than a specific size, so a part of the old cache must be deleted

Comment: Why would you need MATLAB to do that?  You can certainly do that in the terminal.

Comment: I'm working on windows :(

Comment: In Linux / Mac OS, there are efficient ways to do that... in Windows... I'm out of ideas.  From what I have seen with Windows, the only way is to do a byte copy where the input pointer starts at however many bytes you want to skip over.

Comment: And I've used matlab to simulate a lot of stuff in the project.. like joining and leaving the network, and a lot of other networking-related stuff

Comment: I understand.  I don't think you can escape a byte copy.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574115/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-remove-first-n-bytes-from-a-file-on-windows -  Also, see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/01/10097859.aspx

Comment: Well, it says the same things you said, so I can't just escape them like that.. So I'll accept your ideas as the answer to my dilemma..

Comment: just noticed that comments can't be accepted as an answer..I've up-voted them

Comment: Well.. it is an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do this **with** or **without** loading the file into memory?  If you can do this in memory, one possible way is to read in the file with [`fseek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) and [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html), skip the first few bytes, read the rest of the data into memory and save that back into a new file using [`fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html).

In Linux / Mac OS, there are efficient ways to do this without having to load the file in memory.  For example, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6852/best-way-to-remove-bytes-from-the-start-of-a-file

However, if you're in Windows, you can't escape doing a byte copy which ultimately means doing this in memory.   From what I have seen with Windows, the only way is to do a byte copy where the input pointer starts at however many bytes you want to skip over.

See for example here: [What is the most efficient way to remove first N bytes from a file on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574115/), and also here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/01/10097859.aspx

With these posts, you don't have a choice but to do a byte copy.  Therefore, if you want to simulate the same in MATLAB, you'll have to do what I said above.

---

Since you're working in MATLAB, here is some example code to do what I have outlined above:

```
fid = fopen('data', 'r'); %// Open up data file
fid2 = fopen('dataout', 'w'); %// File to save - new file with skipped bytes

skip = 50; %// Determine how many bytes you want to skip over

fseek(fid1, skip, 'bof'); %// Skip over bytes - 'bof' means from beginning of file

A = fread(fid1); %// Read the data
fwrite(fid2, A); %// Write data to new file

%// Close the files
fclose(fid);
fclose(fid2);
```

Comment: Thanks again rayryeng ^_^

Comment: @user3379482 - No problem :) I'm editing my post now to write some code that will help you modify the file using the `fread` approach.  Give me a moment.

Comment: BTW.. your website isn't loading!

Comment: @user3379482 - Which one!? My academic one?  Yeah I need to get rid of that link.... It's not there anymore since I graduated :(

Comment: @user3379482 - Edited my post.  Try that code and see if it works!

Comment: Well I know how to do that in matlab, I was just asking if It's possible to do that directly..still +1 for your great job :)

Comment: @user3379482 - OH... well I'll leave that code there in case anyone else wants to take a look.  Thanks :)